# Django database does not exists in postgreSQL container?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, containers

How can I connect my postgreSQL database container with my django application.

How can I create a database in postgreSQL while building the image but the case is I have separate container for postgreSQL and in this case How can I connect my postgreSQL.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

RUN apt update -y

RUN apt-get install debconf-utils

RUN apt install python3.8 -y

RUN apt install python3-pip -y

RUN echo 'tzdata tzdata/Areas select Asia' | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo 'tzdata tzdata/Zones/Asia select Kolkata' | debconf-set-selections
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt install -y tzdata

RUN apt-get install -y gdal-bin
RUN apt-get install -y libgdal-dev

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app

COPY ./app /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

# RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media

# RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static
# RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
# RUN adduser --disabled-password user
# RUN chown -R user:user /vol
# RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web

# USER user

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services: 
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
    environment: 
      - SECRET_KEY=changeme
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1,localhost
    
    depends_on: 
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - static_data:/static/db
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    container_name: ae73234b58e8
  
  proxy:
    build: 
      context: ./proxy
    volumes: 
      - static_data:/vol/static
    ports: 
      - 80:8080
    depends_on: 
      - app
  
volumes: 
  static_data:
```

So, here I need to create a database while I build the `Dockerfile` image and How can I do that?

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? What is your `DATABASES` configuration like?

Comment: set credential env in `db` section, as same as django db settings

Comment: @AKX and Amin I have change the question please help me with that!

Comment: You still aren't showing the exact error, or your Django DATABASES setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can add environment variables in `db`.
Set the `POSTGRES_DB` environment variable with name of database you use in django. It will be created once postgres is built.